# should I create json annotation for validation images?

Tags: object-detection, faster-rcnn

I am trying to implement mask rcnn for my own dataset but couldnt find any info about annotations for the val folder that contains the images for validattion. I created json annotations using Via 2.0.8 for my training set and that make senese. but if the validation images are the images to test later on why to make annotations for them. I can't train my module without json file in the val folder.

I tried to copy the json annotation for training images to the validation folder. it worker I think but that means I should have the same amount of images in both training and val with same names as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/96869/165527). Basically, you need validation set to validate the output and to measure the performance of your model. After the model is trained using the training set, the validation set is used to measure the model's performance in case of accuracy, average precision, etc. This means that the validation set needs to have similar annotation files (ground truth) as the training set, so that the result of the model's prediction can be compared to the **true** results defined by you. For example, the model performs segmentation on an image and outputs some result. This result is then compared with the annotation (the expected correct output) in the validation set to measure the accuracy of the model's prediction. The test set is just for you to test your model on and see how it is performing. However there is no exact measurements in the test set to calculate the performance and accuracy.

In case of segmentation, one of the popular measurements is the [dice score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient) for which we need the annotations (in validation set) to calculate.

Comment: I have only a training set and a validation set. [matterport](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN) didn't mention any test set in there repo .I read the your answer and the answer you linked, it was a great clarification.still confused ... should the images that goes in the validation set be the same images the goes in the training one? I am using python 3.7 . I will try to split the validation set into two sets and see how it goes...thanks

Comment: The testing set is optional. By **testing set** I mean a number of new images that you can test your model on and see the results; but there is no need to have them. The images that go in the **validation set**, should be different from the images in **training set**. For example, if you have 1000 images, after annotating all 1000, you can use 500 of them as training set and the other 500 as the validation set. After training is done and the accuracy is defined, you can use some new images (other than 1000) to see the performance for your self (these new images are called testing set).

Comment: That is the answer that I was looking for. I understand the concept now. my mistake was that I didn't annotate the images that goes in the training set. now I annotated the training set, then replaced half of it with a test set of images  that has never been annotated. it goes like a charm thanks a million. I need to work on accuracy now.. any useful links on accuracy would be appreciated.

Comment: You can treat the model as an **object detection** model and use regular evaluation metrics like in [here](https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/map-mean-average-precision-for-object-detection-45c121a31173). Or to be more specific about the segmentation evaluation, there are other metrics explained [here](https://www.jeremyjordan.me/evaluating-image-segmentation-models/).